# Sencha Touch - setactiveitem to top level on nested list

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a tabpanel with items of nestedlists.  Each nested list goes several levels deep.  If I drill down one of the nested list, then i click on a different item in the tabpanel, then click back to it, the nested list is still drilled down, instead of refreshing to the top level of the nested list.

How do I get the nestedlist to display the top level instead of the drilled down level everytime I return to it?

**Additional Info**
OK, I'm part way there.  Here's the code I have now:

```
     var tabBar = new Ext.TabPanel({
        fullscreen: true,
        id : 'footer',
        cardSwitchAnimation:false,

          listeners: {

                  cardswitch: {
                           fn: function() { 
                                  Ext.getCmp('footer').getActiveItem().setActiveItem(0);
                             }
                        }
          },

        tabBar: {
           dock: 'bottom'
        },
        items: [/* some nestedlist components */]
     });
```

So the final problem is that everytime I cardswitch, I see the "drillup/slideback" animation of the nested list sliding back or drilling back to the top level item.  How do I get it to just show the top level item without this drill up/slide back animation?  I want to preserve the slide forward and drill down animation when the user drills down the nestedlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the cardSwitchAnimation parameter to false in the setActiveItem method

**[UPDATE] Deselect item**

Add an event listener for the item tap event on the nested list

```
nestedList.on("itemtap", function(nestedlist, index, item, e){setTimeout(function(){nestedlist(index);},500);}, this);
```

**[UPDATE] From John**

For some reason your code didn't do anything for me.  But this one worked:

```
var nestedList = new Ext.NestedList({
      store: store,
      listeners: {
        itemtap: function(dv, ix, item, e) {
            // Clear the selection soon
            setTimeout(function(){dv.deselect(ix);},500);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup that worked too. Now I have a final problem  The former selected item is still high-lighted.  How do I deselect() it?

Comment: I'm having troubel finding a deselectAll() function on the right object, or trying to idnetify the record id, then find hte object function equivalent to deselect() for it.

Comment: Hey TDeBailleul, I noticed a bug in my code that i don't know how to fix.  Although the cardswitch works and takes you back to top level, the back button is not functioning properly.  It appears sometimes at the top level, and other times, it doesn't actually go back at all.  It's as if the activities of the back button lost sync when I execute getActiveItem().  Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: I think that'd be better if you'd start a new question. It would be clearer. Let me know when it's done.

Comment: Ok new question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762888/sencha-touch-back-button-bug-after-setactiveitem-to-top-level-on-nested-list

Answer (score 1):

In March 2014, with version 2.3.1, I had the above problem with the Ext.dataview.NestedList object. The suggested approach of using the "deselect" method did not work for me - probably because of the two years that have gone by since the original question.

To resolve problem, I used the following:

```
nestedList.goToNode( nestedList.getStore().getRoot() );
```